# How do I make VSCode outline global (browse entire folder)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In VS code, there's an outline feature that works for the file currently open. It's great, just what I need!

However, I want to browse the entire class structure of my project, just like you can in qtcreator, and like you can for other programming languages in IntelliJ.

---

**[image: How do I make the visual studio outline global (browse entire folder)?]**

---

This is super important: browsing the class structure is the fastest way for me to navigate between files. Working with my code in qtcreator is a factor of 2 faster due to the qtcreator "outline" being global.

Comment: I changed the title a little because "Visual Studio" and "VSCode" or "Visual Studio Code" are very different IDEs with a similar name. At SO the Visual Studio term and tags refer to the original "Visual Studio Community / Pro / Enterprise" not VSCode.

Comment: a nice subject for a pull request of the C++ language extension you can write